# PHP file upload validation

Tags: php, upload

My php upload script works great and is validated for everything from file type to size except if no file exists. You can just hit the submit button and it will send blank data to the upload script. I was trying this:

```
if (!is_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile1']['name']))
{
        header("location:../index.php?code=no_file");
}
```

It won't work :(

Any way of getting this to work?
-mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I use is the `file_exists($name_of_submitted_file)` function at the end to see whether or not the file has been successfully uploaded.

Comment: Why does no one ever check the error code on PHP uploads...  The file can theoretically exist even if it's not a valid upload.

Answer (score 3):

Check the error code:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

```
if ($_FILES['ufile1']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) { /* no file */ }
```

Note that you should already be checking the error code to make sure that it's UPLOAD_ERR_OK on files that you actually acccept.

Also, $HTTP_POST_FILES is deprecated in favour of $_FILES these days.  That signifies to me that you probably want to find a newer tutorial.

Comment: oops! I didn't know. Thank you!